# Make script stop when window size smaller than x

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to stop a jquery script when window size is smaller than 500px
can you help me.

i have tried to write a var from 0 to 1 when window size is smaller than 500px
and then add this with a if() function. it doesn't work.

the script that i want to stop running:
    [jsfiddle][1]

thx for your help!

ehm yeah stackoverflow i want to text here 10000 words to describe my problem - so sorry i can describe

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/fg5dcuzm/1/
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question. If jsfiddle goes down, no one would be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `resize()` function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w < 500) {
       // stop script
    }
});
```

Or you can run your script only if window is bidder that 500px:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 500) {
       yourFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: and when i load the page, it must do the function too. (sorry for my english ;) )

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($('body').width()<500){
     alert('dont do it'); 
    }else{
      alert('do it');
    }
});
```

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I haven't reviewed your code well to know why Javascript is not working, but I sometimes hack such things with Css.

Using "!important" will make javascript styles not work when the window width is smaller than 500px:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .two, .one {
        left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```